# why not byte.NewBuffer taking full body request?

Tags: go, slack-api

I am new in golang and i am writing a script to send message to slack using incoming webhook.

```
slackBody, _ := json.Marshal(SlackRequestBody{Text: msg, EventName: "xxx", AccountId: "xxx",
        EventTime: "xxxxx", UserName: "xxxx", yyy: "xx", Status: "xx"})
    fmt.Println(string(slackBody))
    //test := ioutil.ReadAll(bytes.NewBuffer(slackBody))
    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, webhookUrl, bytes.NewBuffer(slackBody))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

This post request include only few word of the "req" request.Can you help me to figure out the issue.

Comment: Does json.Marshal return an error?  Show the output of `fmt.Println(string(slackBody))` and the few word of the request.

Comment: @Cerise Limón

output of fmt.Println(string(slackBody)) :
{"text":"Test Message from taybur","EventName":"xxx","AccountID":"xxx","EventTime":"xxx","UserName":"taybur.rahaman","xxx":"xxx","Status":"xxx"}
 it includes only Test Message from taybur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `bytes.NewBuffer()`  here. From slack's side, it recognised the message provided by "text" field only.  You need to re-design your `SlackRequestBody` structure. As you're using the Webhook API to send messages, your request body should follow the structure format given by the `slack`.

```sh
POST https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-type: application/json
{
  "text": ...
  "blocks": ...
  "attachments": ...
  "thread_ts": ...
  "mrkdwn": ... 
  ... ... ...
}
```

- [Message payload](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/payload)
- [Block object](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks)
- [Text object](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/composition-objects#text)

So, your `SlackRequestBody` structure should be something like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type SlackRequestBody struct {
    Text            string  `json:"text"`
    Blocks          []Block `json:"blocks,omitempty"`
    ThreadTimestamp string  `json:"thread_ts,omitempty"`
    Mrkdwn          bool    `json:"mrkdwn,omitempty"`
}

type Block struct {
    BlockID string `json:"block_id,omitempty"`
    Type    string `json:"type"`
    Text    Text   `json:"text"`
}

type Text struct {
    Type string `json:"type"`
    Text string `json:"text"`
}

func main() {
    var payload = &SlackRequestBody{
        Text: "Your message",
        Blocks: []Block{
            {
                Type: "section",
                Text: Text{
                    Type: "plain_text",
                    Text: "User Name: XXXX",
                },
                BlockID: "username",
            },
            {
                Type: "section",
                Text: Text{
                    Type: "plain_text",
                    Text: "Event Time: " + time.Now().String(),
                },
                BlockID: "eventTime",
            },
        },
    }

    data, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(data))

}
```

- [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TlSrMBGEVKZ)

Output:

```
{
   "text":"Your message",
   "blocks":[
      {
         "block_id":"username",
         "type":"section",
         "text":{
            "type":"plain_text",
            "text":"User Name: XXXX"
         }
      },
      {
         "block_id":"eventTime",
         "type":"section",
         "text":{
            "type":"plain_text",
            "text":"Event Time: 2020-03-29 14:11:33.533827881 +0600 +06 m=+0.000078203"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I will recommend you to use the official [go client](https://github.com/slack-go/slack) of slack. It will provide more flexibility. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this awesome answer.I have used go client and found a lot easier to send customize message.
Thanks again.